# SessionCookieConfig empty when retrieved from HttpSession

Tags: spring, session, cookies

I'm working on a filter in a Spring web app that needs to manually respond with a Set-Cookie header. It also programmatically sets an authentication token in Spring's SecurityContext prior to the header's construction, with no session present at the time the filter is processed. For various and strange architectural reasons, it cannot be driven off the <cookie-config> attribute in the web.xml file. I can easily retrieve the ID of the session, but the other information has been elusive to me.

My initial approach was to grab the ServletContext from the filter. This resulted in a SessionCookieConfig class that was empty. I then grabbed the ServletContext off the session, but that also returns a class with no populated attributes. Here's an example of my code:

```
public class SomeFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        /** some logic **/

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthenticationn(getAuthToken())

        HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession();
        SessionCookieConfig sessionConfig = session.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig();
        String headerVal = String.format("%s=%s; Path=/; secure", sessionConfig.getName(), session.getId());
        servletResponse.setHeader("Set-Cookie", headerVal);

        /** some more logic **/

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I thought in theory that this would work, but this is what SessionCookieConfig looks like when I debug the application:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationSessionCookieConfig

httpOnly = false
secure = false
maxAge = -1
comment = null
domain = null
name = null
path = null
context = StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/path]
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and thought that I could get some advice from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SessionCookieConfig sessionConfig =  request.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig();
```